# Counting commuting Pauli Strings of a certain weight

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, abelian-groups

Let a **$n-$length pauli string** represent any tensor product of finitely many pauli matrices, Ex:
$X\otimes Z\otimes \mathbb{I}\otimes Y\otimes \mathbb{I}\otimes X\otimes\cdots\otimes Z$ where the number of matrices (involved in the tensor product) are $n$.

We know that all $n-$length pauli strings form a group, the **Pauli Group** of size $4^n$.

Let the **weight** of an $n-$length pauli string be equal to *the number of non-identity pauli matrices* in it. The number of $n-$length pauli strings with weight $w$ is just:
$\binom{n}{w}3^{w}$.

Can we have a bound (different from the one above) for the *number of **commuting** pauli strings* of weight $w$ ?

If someone could give me some hints for estimating this, it'll be nice.

Comment: "We know that all $n$−length pauli strings form a group, the Pauli Group of size $4^n$." That claim is false. You also need to include phases otherwise it is not closed under multiplication. For example $ XZXZ=-I $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your question to be asking for the maximal size of a set of mutually commuting Pauli strings of weight $w$ and length $n$.

Two Pauli strings of length $n$ commute if and only if they don't have different non-identity entries in any slot. Thus, in a given slot the elements of a set of mutually commuting Pauli strings of length $n$ must have either the identity or one fixed non-identity matrix. Thus a set of mutually commuting Pauli strings of weight $w$ and length $n$ of maximal size is one that contains every possible choice of $w$ non-identity matrices, for which there is only one choice per slot, so the size of such a set is $\binom nw$.

Answer (score 6):

Note that the three operators $X \otimes X$,  $Y \otimes Y$,  $Z \otimes Z$ mutually commute. 
So it is not true that Two Pauli strings of length n commute if and only if they don't have different non-identity entries in any slot.

Answer (score 0):

$ 2^n $ is one such bound.

However it is quite loose and does not depend on $ w $. Indeed it is just a bound in the maximum size of an abelian subgroup. One way to see this bound is to consider that the extraspecial $ 2 $ group $ 2^{2n+1} $ is basically a symplectic vector space $ 2^{2n} $ equipped with an $ \mathbb{F}_2 $ symplectic form. In other words two Pauli strings commute if the symplectic product is trivial and anticommute if the symplectic product is nontrivial. An abelian subgroup of the Pauli group corresponds to an isotropic subspace. A maximal isotropic subspace of the symplectic vector space $ 2^{2n} $ has dimension $ n $, $ 2^n $. So the maximum size of an abelian subgroup of the Pauli group is $ 2^n $.